# Deriving the mean of the Geometric Distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I am missing something that might be trivial in deriving the mean of the geometric distribution function by using expected value identity

$$
\sum_x x \theta (1-\theta)^{x-1}.
$$

Comment: When you receive a helpful answer, you may accept one answer per question. To accept an answer, you simply click on the $\checkmark$ next to the answer you'd like to accept. You get 2 reputation points for every answer you accept. And shortly, with just a little more reputation, you'll be able to upvote all the answers you find helpful, too.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/605083/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2368304/321264

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30732/321264

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1299465/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/301751/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1426233/321264

Answer (score 4):

Letting $\alpha=1-\theta$, we have
$$
\sum_{x=1}^\infty x \theta (1-\theta)^{x-1} = \theta\sum_{x=1}^\infty x \alpha^{x-1} = \theta \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{d}{d\alpha} \alpha^x = \theta\frac{d}{d\alpha}\sum_{x=1}^\infty \alpha^x.
$$
Sum the geometric series.  You'll get an expression that you can readily differentiate with respect to $\alpha$.  Finally, put $1-\theta$ back in place of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for $|r|<1$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k r^k = \frac{r}{(1-r)^2}$$

Comment: My suspicion, thank you

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
E(X)&=\sum_xx\theta(1-\theta)^{x-1}\\&=\theta(1-(1-\theta))^{-2}=\frac{1}{\theta}
\end{align}

#### Alternative: Use Probability generating function(PGF)

Here $P_X(t)=E(t^X)=(1-(1-\theta)t)^{-1}$ if $|t|<\frac{1}{1-\theta}$

So $E(X)=P'_X(t)|_{t=1}=\frac{1}{\theta}$

#### Alternative: Use Moment generating function(MGF)

$M_X(t)=E(e^{tX})=(1-(1-\theta)e^t)^{-1}$ if $|t|<\log\left[\frac{1}{1-\theta}\right]$

So $E(X)=M'_X(t)|_{t=0}=\frac{1}{\theta}$