# Geometric distribution expected value and variance

Tags: probability

I am trying to prove that $E[X] = \frac 1 p $ and $Var[X] = \frac{1-p}{p^2}$ where $X$ follows a geometric distribution with probability $p$. I need to prove it recursively, using the fact that $X$ is $1$ with probability $p$ and $1 + Y$ with probability $(1-p)$ (for some $Y \geq 1$), where $Y$ has the same distribution as $X$.

For $E[X]$ I intuitively figured that $E[X] = 1 * p + (1 + E[Y]) * (1 - p)$ and since $E[X] = E[Y]$ the equation simplifies to the desired $E[X] = 1/p$.

Here is my first issue: I derived the above equation for $E[X]$ based on intuition alone. My thought process was basically: "using the definition of expectation, $E[X] = 1 * p + (1 + Y) * (1 - p)$, ... but wait, $Y$ is a random variable, so I think I need to take its expectation." Is there a way to justify why I was allowed to just take the expectation there?

Now, to compute the variance, I am also using a similar technique using a recurrence, but I run into some trouble:

$$Var[X] = E[(X - E[X])^2] = E[X^2] - \frac 2 p E[X] + \frac 1 {p^2} = E[X^2] - \frac 1 {p^2}$$

The issue is that I don't really know how to compute $E[X^2]$ using a similar recursive technique. I tried $$E[X^2] = 1^2 * p + (1 + E[X])^2 * (1 - p)$$ but that doesn't look right since $E[X]^2 \neq E[X^2]$ in general, and indeed the math doesn't work out when the equation is simplified (unless I made a mistake).

What is the intuition that I'm missing for this problem?

Comment: Can you explain how or where you get the definition that P(X = 1+Y) = 1-p?

Comment: The probability space consists of two events: A: X = 1, or B: X = 1 + Y for some Y. Event A happens with probability p, so event B must happen with probability 1 - p. Also I am thinking about this in terms of coin tosses so X and Y must be integers greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: Two equivalent approaches: One uses the properties of *conditional* expectation, another expresses the random variable $X$ in terms of "conditional events" (e.g. with Iverson brackets) and uses properties of ordinary (*unconditional*) expectation. Below, you have an answer of each kind.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/301751/321264

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1299465/321264,

Answer (score 2):

For an infinite sequence of independent coin tosses with $P(H) = p$ in each toss, let
$$\begin{align}X &= \text{Number of tosses until H occurs}\\ 
 Y&=\text{Number of tosses after the 1st toss until H occurs}\end{align}$$

Then, using [Iverson bracket notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket),

$$ X= 1\cdot[\text{H on 1st toss}] + (1+Y)\cdot[\text{T on 1st toss}]$$
so (because $Y$ and $[\text{T on 1st toss}]$ are independent),

$$E(X) = 1\cdot p + (1+E(X))\cdot(1-p)$$
which implies 
$$E(X) = 1/p.$$

Furthermore, simply squaring the expression for $X$, we have
$$\begin{align}E(X^2) &= E\big(\ [\text{H on 1st toss}]^2 + ((1+Y)\cdot[\text{T on 1st toss}])^2 + 2\cdot (1+Y)\cdot0\ \big)\\
&= E\big(\ [\text{H on 1st toss}] + ((1+Y)^2\cdot[\text{T on 1st toss}]\ \big)\\
&= p + E((1+2Y+Y^2)(1-p)\\
&= p + (1 + 2E(X) + E(X^2)) (1-p) \\
&= p + (1 + 2/p + E(X^2))(1-p)\end{align}$$

giving 
$$E(X^2) = \frac{2-p}{p^2} $$

and finally

$$\mathrm{var} (X) = E(X^2) - (E(X))^2 = \frac{1-p}{p^2}.$$

In the above, we have used the following facts:

- $[\text{T on 1st toss}]\cdot[\text{H on 1st toss}]= 0$
- squaring any Iverson bracket does not change its value
- $Y$ and $[\text{T on 1st toss}]$ are independent

**NB**: The main idea of this approach is to *express the random variable* $X$ directly in terms of the random variable $Y$ (which has the same distribution as $X$) together with appropriate "conditional events" (as Iverson brackets). The resulting expression for $X$ is then easily manipulated to compute $E(X), E(X^2)$, etc. as ordinary expectations (without introducing *conditonal* expectations).

Answer (score 1):

> Here is my first issue: I derived the above equation for $E[X]$  based on intuition alone. My thought process was basically: "using the definition of expectation, $E[X]=1∗p+(1+Y)∗(1−p)$ , ... but wait, $Y$  is a random variable, so I think I need to take its expectation." Is there a way to justify why I was allowed to just take the expectation there?

It's called the **Law of Iterated Expectation**.  (This is sometimes known as the Law of Total Expectation.)

If the probability space can be *partitioned* into a series of *disjoint* events, $\{A_k\}_n$, then:

$$\mathsf E(X) = \sum_{k=1}^n \mathsf E(X\mid A_k)\;\mathsf P(A_k)$$

In this case you are partitioning on the event of a success on the first attempt, and its complement.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X)
 & = \mathsf E(X\mid X{=}1)\,\mathsf P(X{=}1) + \mathsf E(X\mid X{>}1)\,\mathsf P(X{>}1)
\\ & = \mathsf E(X\mid X{=}1)\cdot p + \mathsf E(X\mid X{>}1)\cdot(1-p)
\\ & = 1\cdot p + (1+\mathsf E(X))\cdot(1-p)
\end{align}$$

Because $\mathsf E(X\mid X{>}1) = \mathsf E(X{+}1)$

---

For the variance, particularly the $\mathsf E(X^2)$ term, you can apply it again.

This time, though, $\mathsf E(X^2\mid X{>}1) = \mathsf E((X{+}1)^2)$.

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(X^2) & = \mathsf E(X^2\mid X{=}1)\cdot p + \mathsf E(X^2\mid X{>}1)\cdot(1-p)
\\ & = p + \mathsf E((X+1)^2)\cdot (1-p)
\\ & = p + \mathsf E(X^2+2X+1)\cdot (1-p)
\\ & = p + (\mathsf E(X^2) + 2\mathsf E(X) + 1)\cdot(1-p)
\end{align}$$