# How do you calculate the expected value of geometric distribution without diffrentiation?

Tags: probability-distributions

Is there any way I can calculate the expected value of geometric distribution without diffrentiation? All other ways I saw here have diffrentiation in them.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are basically asking how to calculate $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{k-1}\cdot k$ without using differentiation term by term of $\sum x^k$.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a Geometric distribution?  Say I am trying to toss a coin until I get an $H$.  If my sequence is $TTH$ do you see the length as $2$ or $3$?

Comment: @lulu : "Geometric distribution" can mean the distribution of the number of independent trials needed to get one success, with probability $p$ of success on each trial, or sometimes with probability $p$ of failure on each trial (so the probability of success is $1-p$). In either case it is a distribution supported on the set $\{1,2,3,4,\ldots,\}.$ But it can also mean the distribution of the number of failures before the first success, so that it's supported on the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,\ldots\}. \qquad$

Comment: @lulu It would be better to have some analytical expressions which clarifies the post.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/605083/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30732/321264.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1299465/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/301751/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1426233/321264

Answer (score 20):

The equivalent question outlined in the comments is to find the value of $$S = \sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^{k-1}$$

We can write out the first few terms:

$$S = 1 + 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3 + 5x^4 + 6x^5 + \cdots$$

Multiply by $x$ to get

$$xS = 0 + x + 2x^2 + 3x^3 + 4x^4 + 5x^5 + \cdots$$

Now subtract $xS$ from $S$:

$$S - xS = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + \cdots$$

The right hand side is a standard geometric series, which means, when $|x|<1$,

$$S - xS = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

$$S(1-x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$$

$$ S = \boxed{\frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)^2}}$$

The original series' terms are an [arithmetico-geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence#Derivation), and this trick of multiplying by the common ratio and subtracting can be used for many similar series.

Answer (score 5):

The geometric distribution is memoryless so either you succeed in the initial attempt with probability $p$ or you start again with probability $1-p$ having made a failed attempt,

if the succeeding on the first attempt counts as $1$ attempt:

$$E[X]=p\times 1+(1-p)\times (1+E[X])$$ so $$p\times E[X]=1$$ so  $$E[X]=\frac{1}{p} \text{ attempts}$$

while if succeeding on the first attempt counts as $0$ failures:

$$E[X]=p\times 0+(1-p)\times (1+E[X])$$ so $$p\times E[X]=1-p$$ so  $$E[X]=\frac{1-p}{p} \text{ failures}$$

and naturally $\frac1p = \frac{1-p}p +1$ since you stop at the first successful attempt

Answer (score 3):

$$\Pr(X=x)=p(1-p)^{x-1},x\in\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$$
$$\mu_X=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x\ p(1-p)^{x-1}$$
changing variable $1-p=q$:
$$\mu_X=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x\ (1-q)q^{x-1}=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}x\ q^{x-1}-x\ q^{x}=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}(x+1)\ q^{x}-x\ q^{x}=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}q^{x}=\frac{1}{1-q}=\frac1p$$

Answer (score 3):

I know at least two ways off hand and there are probably others.

First I'll show you a concrete way to do it. After that I'll show you how to express the same thing exactly. (Together these make up **only one** of those "two ways". The other one now appears in the answer posted by "Henry".)
$$
\begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccc}
& 0 & & 1 & & 2 & & 3 & & 4 & & 5 & & 6 \\
\hline
& & & p^1 & + & 2p^2 & + & 3p^3 & + & 4p^4 & + & 5p^5 & + & 6p^6 & + & \cdots & {} \\[12pt] 
= & & & p^1 & + & p^2 & + & p^3 & + & p^4 & + & p^5 & + & p^6 & + & \cdots \\
& & & & + & p^2 & + & p^3 & + & p^4 & + & p^5 & + & p^6 & + & \cdots \\
& & & & & & + & p^3 & + & p^4 & + & p^5 & + & p^6 & + & \cdots \\
& & & & & & & & + & p^4 & + & p^5 & + & p^6 & + & \cdots \\
& & & & & & & & & & + & p^5 & + & p^6 & + & \cdots \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & + & p^6 & + & \cdots \\
& & & & & & & & & & & & & & + & \cdots \\
& & & & & & & & & & & &  & & \vdots
\end{array}
$$
**First** sum each (horizontal) row. Each is a geometric series. **Then** sum the remaining series, which is also geometric.

Here is the same method expressed abstractly in the language of algebra:
\begin{align}
\sum_{x=0}^\infty x (1-p) p^x & = \sum_{x=1}^\infty x (1-p) p^x = \sum_{x=1}^\infty \sum_{j=1}^x (1-p)p^x \\[10pt]
& = \sum_{ x,j\, : \, 1 \,\le\, j \, \le \, x} (1-p) p^x = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{x=j}^\infty (1-p)p^x
\end{align}
Now you're summing a geometric series as $x$ goes from $j-1$ to $\infty,$ and then the outer sum, as $j$ goes from $1$ to $\infty,$ also turns out to be geometric.

(In the very first step above I put $\displaystyle\sum_{x=0}^\infty = \sum_{x=1}^\infty.$ That is justified by the fact that when $x=0,$ the actual term being added is $0$ so it can be dropped.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem can be viewed in a different perspective to understand more intuitively. Let's see the following definition.

*"A person tosses a coin, if head comes he stops, else he passes the coin to the next person. For the next person, he follows the same process: If head comes he stops, else passes the coin to next person and so on."*

So the process can be modelled as,

$$ 
X = 
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if $head$ occurs} \\
1 + Y, & \text{if $tail$ occurs}
\end{cases}
$$

where $Y$ denotes the next person.

Similarly for $Y$, the equation can be written as,
$$ 
Y = 
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if $head$ occurs} \\
1 + Y', & \text{if $tail$ occurs}
\end{cases}
$$
where $Y'$ is the next after $Y$ and so on.

We see that there is no difference between $X$ and $Y$, both toss the coin and stop if head comes else pass the coin to next person who does the same. If both the events were occurring separately and independently (i.e. $Y$ had a coin already and didn't know it came from $X$), their average (or expected) values would be same.

Let's calculate average value of $X$ using the formula of expected values.
Here $p$ is the probability of head and $q$ is the probability of tail.
$$
E(X) = p \times 1 + q \times (1 + Y) \tag{1}\label{eq1}
$$

Let's see the formula in an intuitive way. Suppose we ask $X$, *What is the average number of tosses that you need to get heads?*. He will be like, *My expected value is 1 into p if head occurs in the first toss else (1 + no. of tosses that $Y$ had to make) into q*. And $Y$ is like so *on an average I had to do $E(Y)$ tosses to get heads*. So $X$'s final statement is *1 into p if head comes in first toss else 1 + $E(Y)$ tosses tail comes*.

So equation can be reduced as,

$$
\begin{align}
&E(X) = p \times 1 + q \times (1 + E(Y)) && \text{} \tag{2}\label{eq2} \\
\Rightarrow \ &E(X) = p \times 1 + q \times (1 + E(X)) && \text{Since $E(X) = E(Y)$} \\
\Rightarrow \ &E(X) = 1/p
\end{align}
$$

---

Note that, $\eqref{eq1}$ is very different from $\eqref{eq2}$. 
$(2)$ can be solved as seen above, but $(1)$ just continues to unfold further like $E(X) = 1 \times p + q \times (1 + 1) \times p + q \times (1 + Y') \times q$ and so on. Although this can also be reduced to $E(X) = 1 \times p + q \times (1 + E(X))$, but I wanted to follow the process intuitively.

---

Since it can seem off, to just put the average value of $Y$ in $(1)$, improvements with strong reasoning are welcomed.