# Proof of the law of total expectation using $Y$

Tags: probability

I am given: $Y$ equals $1$ if a success was achieved in the first try (of something, doesn't matter what), and $0$ otherwise.

I need to prove the *expectation of the Geometric distribution* using $Y$ and using the *law of total expectation*.
 I'm not really sure where to start and I need some directions. I know that $E(Y) = E(E(Y | X))$ but what should be my $X$? And how do I even start the proof?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301751/expectation-and-variance-of-the-geometric-distribution

Answer (score 1):

> but what should be my $X$? And how do I even start the proof?

Let $X$ be the count of tries until success in an indefinite sequence of independent Bernoulli trials with identical success rate $p$.   That is, $~X\sim\mathcal{Geo_1}(p)$

$$\mathsf P(X=x) ~=~ p\,(1-p)^{x-1} \cdot\mathsf 1_{x\in\Bbb N^+}$$

Specify that $Y$ is the indicator of success on the first try *of this* geometric distribution.$$Y =\begin{cases} 1 &:& X=1\\0 &:& X>1\end{cases}$$

By the tower principle, $\mathsf E(Y) ~=~ \mathsf E\bigl(\mathsf E(Y\mid X)\bigr)$, aka the Law of Total Expectation:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(Y) ~&=~ \sum_{x=1}^\infty \mathsf P(X=x)~\mathsf E(Y\mid X=x) \\[0ex] &~~\vdots\end{align}$$