# Geometric distribution and expectation of polynomials of random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a random variable geometrically distributed. I have known that geometric distribution is memoryless which means

$P(X>i+j|X>i)=P(X>j)$.

Now I want to compute the value of $E(X(X-1)(X-2)...(X-r+1))=\frac{r!p^r}{(1-p)^r}$.

I see the answer from this post below. But I really don't understand what does $U$ in this answer mean. Is there another way to interpret the solution?
[Expectation and variance of the geometric distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/301751/expectation-and-variance-of-the-geometric-distribution)

Comment: And asking about the meaning of U by posting a comment over there is not an option because?

Comment: Sorry for that. But I was asking for another interpretation of the solution.